# Cancel submit jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is a part of the code from a form requesting data to check if the email alredy exist. The thing is, the program is supposed to return 0 if there is no any mail like this. It dont work properly, because the program keep sending the data, even if the mail is not correct.

If you want more info, or i am missing something let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#enviar").click(function(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();
        var error = false;
        consulta = $("#email2").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "compruebaEmail.php",
            data: "b="+consulta,
            dataType: "html",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){  
                if(data==0){
                    $("#error").html("Email  incorrecto");
                    error = false;
                }else{
                    $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
                }
            }
        }); 
        if (error){     
          return false;   
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my compruebaEmail.php

```
<?php require_once('connections/vinoteca.php'); ?>


<?php

    mysql_select_db($database_vinoteca, $vinoteca);

      $user = $_POST['b'];

      if(!empty($user)) {
            comprobar($user);
      }

      function comprobar($b) {


            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '".$b."'");

            $contar = mysql_num_rows($sql);

            if($contar == 0){
                  echo 0;
            }else{
                  echo 1;
            }
      }     
?>
```

And here goes the POST

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="validarUsu.php">
    <div class="row">
             <span class="center">Email</span>
        </div>
    <div class="row">   
         <input type="text" name="email" id="email2" value="" size="32" />          
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <span class="center">Contrase&ntilde;a</span>       
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="password" name="password"   id="id2" value="" size="32" />
            </div>

     <div class="row">
               <span id="error"> </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Acceder" id="enviar" size="20">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <a href="recuperarPassword.php">Recuperar contrase&ntilde;a</a>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: in a comment to an answer you state that you want to catch the submit event. That is a feature of the form, not of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're returning `false` from your Ajax function. You need to return false from your `click` function. Give this a try:

```
$("#enviar").click(function() {
    var error = false;
    consulta = $("#email2").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "compruebaEmail.php",
        data: "b="+consulta,
        dataType: "html",
        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },
        success: function(data){  
            if(data==0){
                $("#error").html("Email  incorrecto");
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }); 
    if (error)
        return false;   
});
```

Comment: As the same i have told to Cr3aHal0, the program works, when i push the send button, it shows me the error message under the password input, but in less that a half of a second, the page refresh, and i got no message after that. The thing is that i dont want to get the page refreshed. Thanks for your answer anyway. P.S.: I have added the POST method in the original post

Comment: Then you need to identify what code refreshes the page. Nothing in the code you posted above will cause the page to refresh.

Comment: Okay, right now works, but whit this code I can manage the event click, but I would like manage the event subit if is possible,
I have changed the original post. Can you provide me any kind of solution, if it's possible?

Comment: Give your form an ID and then you can do `$('#my-form').submit(function(event) {});`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is canceling the submitting event, then :

Either :

1 - Add the event arg to your click handler :

```
$("#enviar").click(function(event){
```

2 - use event.preventDefault(); when you want to cancel the submit message :)

or change the "return false;" location so that it will be triggered in the "click" handler scope and note the "success" scope e.g with a boolean that would represent if there is an error (EDIT : that is Styphon' solution)

Documentation here : http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: The program works, when i push the send button, it shows me the error message under the password input, but in less that a half of a second, the page refresh, and i got no message after that. The thing is that i dont want to get the page refreshed. Thanks for your answer anyway. P.S.: I have added the POST method in the original post